Why are my custom Eclipse templates not working?
I tryed to write some customized templates in eclipse. All templates but my customized ones works well. When I try to use one of mine from java editor, I will see nothing appens. When I try to use one of mine from template view, I have thoose exceptions:
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.template.java.JavaContext cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.template.java.JavaPostfixContext (org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.template.java.JavaContext and org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.template.java.JavaPostfixContext are in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @4d097a89)

What I have to do to resolve this issue?
Edit
Found!
The name newField returns this issue! I replaced it with the name field and it works well!

The template I tried to write is quite simple: ${result:newName(Classe)} ${newField} = (${result}) Factory.CreateObject(${result}.class);

You can add your comment to the original question. Regardless, which version of Eclipse is this, and how was it installed? This is an error related to that, not your template.

I put the template in a comment because I assumed it wasn't the heart of the question. However, my eclipse says: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components) Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0) Build id: 20231201-2043
It becames from a lot of updates. I installed Ecplise in 2018-03 the first times, and executed updates adding new version software site (like this: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-12 ) every 6 months (I think I will add the 2024-06 soon)

It might be time for a fresh reinstall. Downloadables of that package include a matching JRE.

I reinstalled a blank copy of eclipse (2024-06), but I think a lot of plugin are in the project. I have the same result. Sob

Sounds like it's time to report an Issue to https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/ .
